# Numbering using Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I would like to automate the numbering in my markdown file using pure Jinja2 implementation.

I have been able to achieve **single-level numbering** using the following:

```
{% set number = 1 %}
{% macro set_number() -%}
  {{ number }}
  {%- set number = number + 1 -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

And then, when i call `set_number()`; for example:

```
## Test Heading {{ set_number() }}
```

it renders just fine.

However, it is **second-level numbering** that i am struggling with. I would like to have a numbering scheme such as 1, 2a, 2b, 2c, 3, 4a, 4b... and so on. I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

**Option 1**

```
{% set number = 1 %}
{% set sub_number = 'a' %}

{% macro set_number() -%}
  {{ number }}{{ sub_number }}
  {%- set sub_number = sub_number|int + 1 %}
  {%- set sub_number_2 = sub_number|string %}
  {%- if sub_number_2 > 'z' -%}
    {%- set number = number + 1 -%} 
    {%- set sub_number = 'a' -%}
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

And then, when i call the function; for example:

```
## Test heading {{ set_number() }}
## Test heading {{ set_number() }}
## Test heading {{ set_number() }}
## Test heading {{ set_number() }}
```

The output of option 1 is as follows:

```
Test heading 1a  
Test heading 11  
Test heading 12  
Test heading 13  
Test heading 14
```

**Option 2**

I also tried the following, but it does not work. The Python function `chr()` and `ord()` do not work:

```
{% set number = 1 %}
{% set sub_number = 'a' %}
{% macro set_number() -%}
  {{ number }}{{ sub_number }}
  {%- set sub_number = chr(ord(sub_number) + 1) %}
  {%- if sub_number > 'z' -%}
    {%- set number = number + 1 -%}
    {%- set sub_number = 'a' -%}
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Can someone please guide me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jinja has a [`cycler` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-globals.cycler) that can be used for this if we provide the letters as a list. We can use `letter.current` attribute the check whether we need to increase the header number by one.

```
{% set heading = namespace(number=0) %}
{% set letter = cycler(*'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'|list) %}

{% macro set_header() -%}
  {%- if letter.current == 'a' %}
    {%- set heading.number = heading.number + 1 %}
  {%- endif %}
  {{ heading.number }}{{ letter.next() }}
{%- endmacro %}
```

This will produce: 1a, 1b, 1c, ... 1z, 2a, 2b.

### Manually turn on the letter subheader

In this version we can turn on the letter subheader with the `sub=True` parameter of our macro. We also need a new tracking variable in the namespace object (`heading.last_sub`) that tells us when we are in a letter series.

```
{% set heading = namespace(number=0, last_sub=None) %}
{% set letter = cycler(*'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'|list) %}

{%- macro set_header(sub=False) %}
{%- if sub == False or heading.last_sub == False %}
{%- set heading.number = heading.number + 1 %}
{%- set reset = letter.reset() %}
{%- endif %}
{{ heading.number }}{% if sub %}{{ letter.next() }}{% endif %}
{%- set heading.last_sub = sub %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

For this code:

```
{{ set_header() }}
{{ set_header() }}
{{ set_header(True) }}
{{ set_header(True) }}
{{ set_header(True) }}
{{ set_header() }}
{{ set_header() }}
{{ set_header(True) }}
{{ set_header(True) }}
```

it will produce the following series: 1, 2, 3a, 3b, 3c, 4, 5, 6a, 6b.

Comment: Thanks Dauros. I have a follow-up please. But what if i wanted the following sequence: 

1, 2, 3a, 3b, 3c, 4, 5, 6a, 6b...

How can i achieve both first-level and second-level numbering?

Comment: You mean you want to have an option that turns on the letter subheaders? E.g. `set_header(letter=True)`?

Comment: Yes, i guess that's right, Dauros.

Comment: Dauros, this worked just fine. thanks so much. I have a quick follow-up:

Why do you have the following check: `sub and heading.last_sub == False`
Why not just `heading.last_sub == False`

Comment: You're right, it's unnecessary, it was just a leftover from the prototyping phase, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Dauros, i am also curious, what does the following do:
{%- set reset = letter.reset() %}

Why are we setting the value of `letter.reset()` to variable `reset`?

Comment: It's just a little trick to prevent the printing of the `None` return value from `.reset()`. I forgot to use the conventional `_` to indicate the return value is discarded.

Comment: How would that manifest in code please: the use of underscore to discard the return value

Comment: The `letter.reset()` is not a statement, so normally I have to put it between braces `{{ letter.reset() }}` but this outputs an unnecessary `None` string. With the 'set' trick I store this `None` string into an unused variable.